# why is this controller function called more than once

Tags: angularjs

Code below (also in [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/fCXn5HMWU35pdY2REi8z?p=info)). On the console I see multiple `foo`s getting printed.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular.min.js'></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div ng-app='theApp'>
      <div ng-controller='TheController as ctl'>
        {{ctl.foo()}}
      </div>
    </div>
    <script>
     angular.module('theApp', [])
            .controller('TheController', [function() {
              this.foo = function() {
                console.log('foo');
              };
            }]);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your view expression is the result of a function call, the watch listener will invoke it multiple times to detect if the function result is stable.  For comparison, see this [fork of the example code](http://plnkr.co/edit/O7BOvhEWtT0o81E4ecHQ?p=preview), and note how the function foo is only called one time.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular.min.js'></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div ng-app='theApp'>
      <div ng-controller='TheController as ctl'>
        {{ctl.bar}}
      </div>
    </div>
    <script>
     angular.module('theApp', [])
            .controller('TheController', [function() {
              this.foo = function() {
                console.log('foo');
                return "foo";
              };
              this.bar = this.foo();
            }]);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```